# display image and text inline and vertically centered

Tags: css

Im trying to display an image and text inline like this:

IMAGE TEXT

the image is a circle so i want the text to be vertically in the centre of the image as the image is a little bigger than the text

this is what i have so far:

```
#contactinfo-text {
    font-size:30px;
    color:#F36F25;
    display:inline;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
#contactinfo-text:hover {
    color:#666666;
}

<img src="../images/icons/telephone.png" height="60" /><div id="contactinfo-text">01702 66 77 27</div>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the vertical-align property:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/Hwq3Z/

Comment: thats better - but any ideas why the text isnt changing font size? http://jsfiddle.net/Hwq3Z/1/ i have added another div for background color etc...

Comment: @CharlieFord You are missing a hash. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/Hwq3Z/3/

Comment: hmm ok cool - my mistake :)
any ideas how to make it all display centre rather than right? http://jsfiddle.net/Hwq3Z/4/